# Building a flow in a library with check in/out system

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow, flow, power-automate, check-out

I am not sure if this video is the right topic, but it is pretty close to it.

I am also building a flow, which is automatically filling the right column. The problem is, we have a check in/out system up in the libraries.

It is easy to build a flow which is checking out all files, updating the column and finally checking them all back again.

Problem: There are some files, which are already checked out by other colleges.
How can I filter my "get files (properties only)" pick the right way not to touch files checked out by other people. Somehow I can't "touch" the "Checked Out To" column using filter Query: `Checked Out To eq ''`

Does a solution for this exist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add filter on `CheckoutUserId` column for your requirements.

**Example**:

If you want to fetch the files which are not checked out to any user then you can achieve this using below configuration:

[image]

**Filter query**:

```
CheckoutUserId eq null
```

---

Similarly if you want to get the files which are not checked out by other users & the files which are checked out to you, you can use filter query like below:

```
CheckoutUserId eq null or CheckoutUserId eq 6
```

Where `6` is your SharePoint user ID.